# REST update on entity's joint value: do it by key or by value?

Tags: rest

I'm developing my first REST API, and have a design question.

> I would like to use this api in a native Android mobile application

Suppose I have a Car table and a Brand table, like this:

```
Car( car_id, name, brand_id );
Brand( brand_id, name );
```

How do I represent the joint of Car and Brand in the Rest api updates and reads?

**Use-cases:**

1) User reads his car: in the response, it's enough to send the *brand name*, we do not care about the *brand id*, it's meaningles to the user.

2) User wants to update car data: We have to do a *1)* first, to retrieve current details of the car, then represent a select list to the user to chose from brands.

**THE QUESTION**

Should I represent two kind of read for my Car entity: one for updates with brand id, another for reads with brand name?

Or should I repeatedly ask for joint table: Brand; cache it; then in my car read method, only the brand id would be represented, and join the value from my mobile app's brand cache?

which way to go?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so much about database schema and joins when designing your API. Instead, think about how your resources should be modeled and accessed via HTTP in a RESTful manner.

Use-case 1 should be served by a GET on a Car URI (say, `https://your.api/car/787`). That should return all the relevant details about a single Car in the body of the response (that's the "representation" of your Car resource). For example, a JSON response body might be this:

```
{
  "id" : "123",
  "name" : "Ford Mustang",
  "brand" : "https://your.api/brand/53"
}
```

If an API client wants details about the brand, they can GET the URI `https://your.api/brand/53` to get all the JSON details about it.

For use-case 2, that should be done by having the client PUT a new representation of the Car to the same Car URI as above (`https://your.api/car/787`). If they wish to change the brand, they will need to have the new brand URI available before calling PUT in order to pass it in the update request. They could get the full list of brands by calling GET on a collection URI such as `https://your.api/brands` and then passing the desired brand URI within the request body.

Keep in mind that properly-designed RESTful APIs are **stateless**. Each request/response should be complete and self-contained, and should contain enough data within them to complete an entire read, update or removal operation.

Comment: This seems very good at design, but has overhead in my case (something I wouldn't want in a mobile client): notice, that from brand, I only want a name. making a link to brand (in your example) would end up in two requests for READ. If I want to list 10 cars, I would need 1 listing + 10 brand listing. If other properties exist, thats another 10 request, resulting in 21 requests for a single listing.

Comment: Then feel free to de-normalize your payloads to reduce the amount of GETs required. Return enough data within a GET to `Car` to allow the client to see more information about brands, etc in the response. Keep in mind that this kind of optimization might lead to a very jumbled and brittle API as it bunches many resources together.

Comment: Maybe I got your answer wrong at first, because I defined two name attributes (one in car, one in brand), and I was not sure which one you used. But it seems like what I eventually come up with: including both brand name and brand id in the same response. Pls assure me if I'm right.

By the way the "id as URI" is a good idea.

Comment: The one I used was for Car. You can have similarly-named fields in each of your resource's representations, as long as it's clear to the client which is which. And yes, having brand name and brand id in the same response would be fine.